# Using UNION with three queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to merge three separate queries into one using the UNION function of MYSQL.

I want to output one table of data that contains the **booking_count**, **reserve_count** and **cancel_count**. Some rows will have values for all three, some will only have values for one.

I wonder if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong?

The errors I am getting are:

Notice: Undefined index: cancel_count 
Notice: Undefined index: reserve_count

I assume this is a problem with the MYSQL query as the PHP looks fine

```
$query = "SELECT id, class_date, class_id, COUNT(*) AS booked_count   
          FROM bookings
          WHERE booking_status='#BOOKED#'
          UNION ALL

          SELECT id, class_date, class_id, COUNT(*) AS reserve_count  
          FROM bookings
          WHERE booking_status='#RESERVE#'
          UNION ALL

      SELECT id, class_date, class_id, COUNT(*) AS cancel_count  
          FROM bookings
          WHERE booking_status='#CANCELLED#'
          GROUP BY class_date, class_id
          ORDER BY class_date ASC, class_id ASC" ;

$result = mysqli_query($sql,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $union[$row['id']] = array('class_date' => $row['class_date'], 'class_id' => $row['class_id'], 'booked_count' => $row['booked_count'], 'reserve_count' => $row['reserve_count'], 'cancel_count' => $row['cancel_count']);
}

echo '<table><tr><th>id</th><th>class_id</th><th>class_date</th><th>booking_number</th><th>reserve_number</th><th>cancelled_number</th></tr>';

foreach($union as $union) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; // id
   echo '<td>'.$union['class_id'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$union['class_date'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$union['booked_count'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$union['reserve_count'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$union['cancel_count'].'</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing now.?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd added that to the end of the question, I'll edit. The error is:                                                   Notice: Undefined index: cancel_count in 
Notice: Undefined index: reserve_count in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
SELECT id, class_date, class_id,
  SUM(booked_count) AS booked_count,
  SUM(reserve_count) AS reserve_count,
  SUM(cancel_count) AS cancel_count
FROM
(SELECT id, class_date, class_id,
  1 AS booked_count,
  0 AS reserve_count,
  0 AS cancel_count 
FROM bookings
WHERE booking_status = '#BOOKED#'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, class_date, class_id,
  0 AS booked_count,
  1 AS reserve_count,
  0 AS cancel_count 
FROM bookings
WHERE booking_status = '#RESERVE#'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, class_date, class_id,
  0 AS booked_count,
  0 AS reserve_count,
  1 AS cancel_count  
FROM bookings
WHERE booking_status = '#CANCELLED#') AS t
GROUP BY class_date, class_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are doing UNION and having different column names  so it will not work, try as

```
$query = "SELECT id, class_date, class_id, COUNT(*) AS booked_count, 0 as reserve_count, 0  as  cancel_count 
          FROM bookings
          WHERE booking_status='#BOOKED#'
          UNION ALL

          SELECT id, class_date, class_id, 0 as booked_count, COUNT(*) AS reserve_count ,0  as  cancel_count 
          FROM bookings
          WHERE booking_status='#RESERVE#'
          UNION ALL

          SELECT id, class_date, class_id, 0 as booked_count, 0 as reserve_count, COUNT(*) AS cancel_count  
          FROM bookings
          WHERE booking_status='#CANCELLED#'
          GROUP BY class_date, class_id
          ORDER BY class_date ASC, class_id ASC" ;
```

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, that does make sense! However I still don't seem to have it quite right, the class_id's haven't merged and the first booking_count value seems to have the value of the whole column added together

Comment: I've fixed that by adding GROUP BY to the first two queries, strangely though it still doesn't merge by class id, it duplicates the rows where there is an entry in each of the count columns

Comment: well the problem is when you do count(*) in the query it will always return one single row, so doing unions you will end up 3 rows in total.

Comment: That makes sense, might have to merge the array with PHP perhaps.

Comment: can you add the tables and some data in http://sqlfiddle.com, since group by will list them group by but instead of `count(*)` try as `sum(booking_status='#BOOKED#') as booked_count` and so on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51759/discussion-between-abhik-chakraborty-and-mkc)